# How to put sidekiq into Docker in a rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, sidekiq

I am using rails, sidekiq and docker.

My docker-compose.yml file

```
sidekiq:
  build: .
  command: bundle exec sidekiq -C config/sidekiq.yml
  links:
    - db
    - redis
```

config/sidekiq.yml file

```
:pidfile: ./tmp/pids/sidekiq.pid
:logfile: ./log/sidekiq.log
:queues:
  - default
```

After I run `docker-compose up`, the sidekiq service can not start rightly.

```
sidekiq_1 | No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - /testapp/tmp/pids/sidekiq.pid
sidekiq_1 | /usr/local/bundle/gems/sidekiq-3.5.3/lib/sidekiq/cli.rb:365:in `initialize'
sidekiq_1 | /usr/local/bundle/gems/sidekiq-3.5.3/lib/sidekiq/cli.rb:365:in `open'
sidekiq_1 | /usr/local/bundle/gems/sidekiq-3.5.3/lib/sidekiq/cli.rb:365:in `write_pid'
sidekiq_1 | /usr/local/bundle/gems/sidekiq-3.5.3/lib/sidekiq/cli.rb:42:in `parse'
sidekiq_1 | /usr/local/bundle/gems/sidekiq-3.5.3/bin/sidekiq:12:in `<top (required)>'
sidekiq_1 | /usr/local/bundle/bin/sidekiq:16:in `load'
sidekiq_1 | /usr/local/bundle/bin/sidekiq:16:in `<main>'
testapp_sidekiq_1 exited with code 1
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Try to mount the volumes. Your `docker-compose` file should look like this (with PosgtreSQL as database) :

```
web:
  build: .
  volumes:
    - .:/myapp
  links:
    - db
    - redis
  ports:
    - "3000:3000"
  command: bundle exec rails server -b 0.0.0.0
sidekiq:
  build: .
  volumes:
    - .:/myapp
  links:
    - db
    - redis
  command: bundle exec sidekiq
db:
  image: postgres
redis:
  image: redis
```

Comment: Thank you. Can this method load the sidekiq config file `-C config/sidekiq.yml`?

Comment: it seems handy to specify the REDIS_URL also

Comment: Why do both the `sidekiq` and ` web` containers need to be mapped to the same external directory? Why can't they each use a copy of /myapp inside their respective containers? I get the above error if I don't map the volumes.

Comment: Resolve the above issue and was able to use a copy from inside the container by adding:

`RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/soloid-api/tmp/pids`

To my dockerfile. Unlike rails Sidekiq doesn't create a `pids` folder and gets confused.

Comment: in this case sidekiq and web both create 2 container. How i can configure in one container both services. Thanks

Comment: I dont think sidekiq needs the db link?

Answer (score 41):

A little bit more details in general on how to put Sidekiq into Docker in a Rails application. And for your reference, all the code is available on [a GitHub repository](https://github.com/yucigou/dockerize_rails_sidekiq).

#### Configure a Redis container

Sidekiq [depends on Redis](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq). So first of all, you need a Redis container to run alongside.

In your docker-compose.yml, add (as an example):

```
redis:
  image: redis:4.0-alpine
```

#### Dockerize Sidekiq

Share the same Dockerfile with your Rails app:

```
FROM ruby:2.3.3
RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y build-essential libpq-dev nodejs
RUN mkdir /myapp
WORKDIR /myapp
ADD Gemfile /myapp/Gemfile
ADD Gemfile.lock /myapp/Gemfile.lock
RUN bundle install
ADD . /myapp
```

Update your docker-compose.yml

```
sidekiq:
  build: .
  command: bundle exec sidekiq
  depends_on:
    - redis
  volumes:
    - .:/myapp
  env_file:
    - .env
```

The environment file .env looks like this:

```
JOB_WORKER_URL=redis://redis:6379/0
```

Also in your docker-compose.yml, add sidekiq to your Rails application's dependency list:

```
web:
  build: .
  command: bundle exec rails s -p 3000 -b '0.0.0.0'
  volumes:
    - .:/myapp
  ports:
    - "3000:3000"
  depends_on:
    - db
    - sidekiq
  env_file:
    - .env
```

#### Add to your Gemfile

```
gem 'sidekiq'
gem 'sidekiq-scheduler'
gem 'sidekiq-unique-jobs'
gem 'sinatra', require: nil
```

The sinatra gem is needed for the Sidekiq web UI (the dashboard shown below)

#### Configure Sidekiq

Add file config/initializers/sidekiq.rb:

```
sidekiq_config = { url: ENV['JOB_WORKER_URL'] }

Sidekiq.configure_server do |config|
  config.redis = sidekiq_config
end

Sidekiq.configure_client do |config|
  config.redis = sidekiq_config
end
```

#### Add a Sidekiq worker

Under directory app/workers/, add a file my_worker.rb:

```
class MyWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker
  def perform(who, message)
    logger.info "Message from #{who} is #{message}"
  end
end
```

That's it. Now you can submit a job in Rails, e.g., in a controller.

```
MyWorker.perform_async(who, message)
```

And the worker will pick up the job, and output a message in the log file.

#### Build and run with docker compose

Once everything is in place, you can build docker images and run your app with docker compose:

```
docker-compose build
docker-compose up

$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                  COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
c0515ac60a8b        hellosidekiq_web       "bundle exec rails..."   23 minutes ago      Up 23 minutes       0.0.0.0:3000->3000/tcp   hellosidekiq_web_1
080e33963e3a        hellosidekiq_sidekiq   "bundle exec sidekiq"    23 minutes ago      Up 23 minutes                                hellosidekiq_sidekiq_1
80d1c03f0573        redis:4.0-alpine       "docker-entrypoint..."   4 days ago          Up 23 minutes       6379/tcp                 hellosidekiq_redis_1
5915869772e4        postgres               "docker-entrypoint..."   4 days ago          Up 23 minutes       5432/tcp                 hellosidekiq_db_1
```

#### Test

Now open the following URL to submit a job:

```
http://localhost:3000/job/submit/John/Prepare%20ye%20the%20way
```

And in the log file, you will see something like this:

```
sidekiq_1  | 2017-11-13T17:08:45.876Z 1 TID-qw47g MyWorker JID-b7b6d39b0d5193cd01e97cb1 INFO: Message from John is Prepare ye the way
```

#### Sidekiq dashboard

If you would like to use the Sidekiq dashboard, as below

[image]

You can add the route to your routes.rb

```
require 'sidekiq/web'
require 'sidekiq-scheduler/web'

Rails.application.routes.draw do
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
  mount Sidekiq::Web => '/sidekiq'

  get 'job/submit/:who/:message', to: 'job#submit'
end
```

Hope it helps.

By the way, if you would like to find out how to dockerize your Rails application using docker compose, refer to [docker compose documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/rails/).

Comment: You are the absolute best, @Yuci!