# Error starting sidekiq in Docker: "Please point sidekiq to a Rails 4/5 application"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, redis, sidekiq

Rails 5.2, Docker Compose, Sidekiq, Redis.

This is the docker-compose file:

```
version: '3.6'

services:
  redis:
    image: 'redis:4.0-alpine'
    command: redis-server
    ports:
      - '6379:6379'
    volumes:
      - 'redis:/data'

  sidekiq:
    depends_on:
      - 'redis'
    build: .
    command: bundle exec sidekiq -C config/sidekiq.yml
    volumes:
      - './:/app'
    env_file:
      - '.env'

  api:
    build: .
    volumes:
      - './:/app'
    working_dir: /app
    command: puma
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    depends_on:
      - db
      - redis
    environment:
      DATABASE_URL: postgres://postgres@db
  db:
    image: postgres:10.3-alpine

volumes:
  redis:
  postgres:
```

It seems sidekiq cannot find my Rails app.

If I change sidekiq to start like this:

```
    command: bundle exec sidekiq -C config/sidekiq.yml -r /app
```

then I get this error:

> Spring was unable to find your config/application.rb file. Your
>   project root was detected at /api, so spring looked for
>   /api/config/application.rb but it doesn't exist. You can configure the
>   root of your application by setting Spring.application_root in
>   config/spring.rb.

If I instead add the `working_dir` setting to sidekiq:

```
sidekiq:
    depends_on:
      - 'redis'
    build: .
    command: bundle exec sidekiq -C config/sidekiq.yml
    volumes:
      - './:/app'
    env_file:
      - '.env'
    working_dir: 
      - '/app'
```

then I get this error:

```
2019-05-27T20:27:59.770Z 1 TID-gr1e0d7n5 INFO: Booting Sidekiq 5.1.1 with redis options {:url=>"redis://redis:6379/0", :id=>"Sidekiq-server-PID-1"}
sidekiq_1  | could not connect to server: No such file or directory
sidekiq_1  |    Is the server running locally and accepting
sidekiq_1  |    connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

So how do I make sidekiq start correctly in its container?

I have seen these answers, which are similar but not this particular error:

[Question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48802444/rails-docker-sidekiq-error-connecting-to-redis-on-127-0-0-16379-errnoe?rq=1)

[Question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34115213/redis-raise-error-noauth-authentication-required-but-there-is-no-password-setti)

[Question 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33563161/how-to-put-sidekiq-into-docker-in-a-rails-application)

[Question 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33765982/sidekiq-not-starting-with-bundle-exec)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems sidekiq could not find the Rails app, which is fixed by adding the 'working-dir' setting, and then it could not find postgres, so I had to add the environment setting to point to postgres.

The final compose file is:

```
version: '3.6'

services:
  db:
    image: postgres:10.3-alpine
    ports:
      - '5432:5432'

  redis:
    image: 'redis:4.0-alpine'
    command: redis-server
    ports:
      - '6379:6379'
    volumes:
      - 'redis:/data'

  sidekiq:
    depends_on:
      - 'db'
      - 'redis'
    build: .
    command: bundle exec sidekiq -C config/sidekiq.yml
    volumes:
      - './:/app'
    env_file:
      - '.env'
    working_dir: /app
    environment:
      DATABASE_URL: postgres://postgres@db

  api:
    build: .
    volumes:
      - './:/app'
    working_dir: /app
    command: puma
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    depends_on:
      - db
      - redis
    environment:
      DATABASE_URL: postgres://postgres@db

volumes:
  redis:
  postgres:
```

Comment: thank you for this. It solved the problem for me as well.

Comment: @paulmiller3000 My pleasure. Thanks for the upvote!